# Virtualbox Ubuntu Guest on Windows 10 is very slow at rendering graphics

Tags: ubuntu, virtualbox, graphics-card

I have a good Windows 10 gaming computer.

Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-10750H CPU @ 2.60GHz, 2592 Mhz, 6 Core(s), 12 Logical Processor(s)

NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1650 Ti

I frequently (only) develop in a Ubuntu VM (been scarred from dual booting in the past, though I'd like to). I use Virtualbox.

However, I'm working on some graphics assignments and I've been noticing that my renders (shaders, models, and such) are very slow. Seems much slower than they should be. These are basic things and I've certainly had smooth experiences with games on the windows host.

So I am wondering what I can do to hopefully speed this up. With the upcoming winter break I might brace myself and dabble back into dual booting but want to avoid this for now. I'd really like to have a Ubuntu only PC but I want to keep windows for the odd thing it does better (like run games). But for now, I don't think that's feasible.

My VM has 6 processors and 8192MB of memory. 16mb of video memory (just bumped up from 12, no effect). VMSVGA controller and 3D acceleration disabled (seemed to freeze on login with this on).

Comment: That may be a Virtual Box issue (not the fastest VM app) and you may have a slow hard drive.   Try VMware if you wish and you need a fast machine (fast SSD).  I have a VMware Windows 10 VM on a fast SSD and it works fine.

Comment: Your host has a 1650 Ti. Your VM has a potato GPU with half of the VRAM my computer had 20 years ago. Are Guest Additions installed?

Comment: What's your storage?  How much total RAM do you have?  Installed the Guest additions?  How about upping VMRAM to 128MB?  What version of VBox, are you current?